# How to stop navigation bar title from changing color when moving from controller to controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I have two controllers that are linked together (via show e.g push) so when I click a button it will go to another view controller. This obviously creates a back arrow to back to the previous controller which is what I want.

However, if I change the style and text of the back button to what ever I want, it then causes the previous controller to take on the characteristics of the other view controller, which is something I don't want to do.

So essentially what I am asking is, how would you stop the characteristics of one controller going on to another one when swiping back?

Here is the code I use of most view controllers:

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = . 
   [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.darkGray,
         NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir Next", size: 20)!]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = " "
```

There are slight variations on different controllers, but this does nothing as it changes when going back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a view controller modifies the properties of a navigation controller (or its navigation bar) then the changes will appear in all view controllers sharing that navigation controller.

If you want the changes to only appear for one view controller then you should make the changes in the `viewWillAppear` of that one view controller and you should reset the changes in the `viewWillDisappear` of that same view controller. This way the changes are (mostly) only visible from that one view controller.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Just wanted to ask, how would I reset the changes so they don't go on to other controllers? Thank you so much for your help again!

Comment: Add code that sets the same changed properties back to their original values.